# Why isn't my C socket server recieving data

Tags: c, sockets, actionscript

I've set up a very simple C socket server, there are two files.

main.c:

```
#include "socket_server.h"
#include "main.h"

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    start_socket_server(SOCKET_SERVER_PORT);

    while (1)
    { 
        update_clients();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

socket_server.c:

```
#include "socket_server.h"

int listen_fd, fdmax, newfd, nbytes, i, j, k;
char buf[256];
fd_set master;
fd_set read_fds;
struct timeval tv;

void start_socket_server(int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    FD_ZERO(&master);
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    bzero( &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 100;

    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    listen(listen_fd, 10);

    FD_SET(listen_fd, &master);
    fdmax = listen_fd;
}

void update_clients()
{
    read_fds = master;
    select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    for(i = 0; i<= fdmax; i++)
    {
        if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds))
        {
            if (i == listen_fd)  //new connection
            {
                newfd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);

                if (newfd != -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "New connection!");
                    FD_SET(newfd, &master);

                    if (newfd > fdmax) {
                        fdmax = newfd;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
                if(nbytes <= 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Dead");
                    close(i);
                    FD_CLR(i, &master);
                } else {
                    for(j = 0; j <= fdmax; j++)
                    {
                        if(FD_ISSET(j, &master))
                        {
                            if(j != listen_fd && j != i)
                            {
                                fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf);
                            }
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a simple flash file to connect to it with the following actionscript:

```
var socket = new XMLSocket;

socket.connect("12.34.56.78", 8080);

socket.onConnect = function(status) {
    if(status) {
        trace("connected");
        socket.writeUTF("Hello!");
        socket.flush();
    } else {
        trace("couldn't connect");
    }
};
```

If I run the server, then my actionscript, I would expect the following:

1. Server sits and waits
2. Flash file starts
3. Server says "New connection!" and flash file says "connected"
4. Server says "Hello!".

Only 1-3 happen. "Hello!" is never output to my terminal. In fact as best I can tell this block:

```
nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
if(nbytes <= 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Dead");
    close(i);
    FD_CLR(i, &master);
 } else {
    for(j = 0; j <= fdmax; j++)
    {
        if(FD_ISSET(j, &master))
        {
            if(j != listen_fd && j != i)
            {
                 fprintf(stderr, "%s", buf);
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Is never executed at all (except for when I close my flash file and the server prints "Dead".

What's going on? Why can't I see the data sent from flash? I've managed to send data TO flash, but I haven't been able to receive any FROM it. Also this is being run from within flash, so there is no need to worry about policy files at this stage.

Comment: You tagged this as AS3 but that code looks like AS1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set all your sockets to be non-blocking.  For example,

```
void start_socket_server(int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    int val;

    FD_ZERO(&master);
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
    bzero( &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 100;

    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (-1 == ioctl(listen_fd, FIONBIO, (val = 1, &val)))
    {
        perror("ioctl failed!\n");
        goto ERROR;  /* TODO: or however else you want to deal with errors */
    }

    bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    listen(listen_fd, 10);

    FD_SET(listen_fd, &master);
    fdmax = listen_fd;
}

...

    if (i == listen_fd)  //new connection
    {
        newfd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) NULL, NULL);

        if (newfd != -1)
        {
            int val;

            fprintf(stderr, "New connection!");

            if (-1 == ioctl(newfd, FIONBIO, (val = 1, &val)))
            {
                perror("ioctl failed!\n");
                goto ERROR;  /* TODO: or however else you want to deal with errors */
            }

            FD_SET(newfd, &master);

            if (newfd > fdmax) {
                fdmax = newfd;
            }
        }
    } else {
          nbytes = recv(i, buf, sizeof buf, 0);
            if(nbytes <= 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Dead");
                close(i);
                FD_CLR(i, &master);
            } else {
                fprintf(stdout, "Received %d bytes: '%s'\n", nbytes, buf);
            }
        }
```

You should also do this on your main listening socket too after you create it initially so that you can't get stuck in a call to accept() somehow.

Also, the way you are outputting read-in data doesn't make much sense.  As initially posted, the code would only print out if it had multiple client connections established.  Then, when data was read in, it would print it N - 1 times, where N was the number of current client connections.

Comment: Sorry can you be a bit more specific? I don't really know where to put that.

Comment: Could you put an example in your answer, with reference to listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); please?

Comment: Should the fd in -1 == ioctl(fd, FIONBIO, (val = 1, &val)) be i?

Comment: OK this seems to make sense to me now. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Also, you are calling select with only a 100us timeout.  If this is all your program is doing, then you should probably call it with NULL as your timeout rather than tight looping like this.  Also, your print out when you read in data doesn't make much sense.  After reading, it will only print out if there is another file descriptor that you are monitoring for readability.  Indeed it will print out the read-in input once for each such other monitored fd.

Comment: @jschultz410 is correct. Your `select` loop is stuck on the first occurrence of blocking socket. Why don't you use `epoll` instead of `select`?

Comment: I've simply been following this tutorial: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

Comment: The behaviour is exactly the same when using ioctl. I'm not convinced this is the problem since in the tutorial I linked there is an example of a simple chat server written in a very similar way.

Comment: The important ioctl is after you call accept.  The initial ioctl after you call socket is less important for functionality, but should be done for safety's sake.  Without the ioctl after accept, the socket will be in blocking mode and when data arrives, it may block in the read waiting for a full 256 bytes from the sender.

Comment: The ioctl after accept doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Did you see my other comment where this won't print anything unless you have another fd you are monitoring for readability?

Comment: Can you explain how I can modify my code to implement that? The tutorial I linked doesn't seem to do anything along those lines.

Comment: That still does nothing. It never even gets in to that else block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71068/discussion-between-jschultz410-and-cameron-ball).